# What exactly triggers the music change?

Tags: game-dev-story

The music in the game recently changed from the kind of bubbly, happy music that it starts out as, to kind of ominous, glitchy sounding music. It sounds like a negative of an image looks.

I tried to think back to what I did before I noticed the new music, and all I can remember is I think I had a Hacker attempt a boost, and they did an awful job (I got like 5 points or something). It seemed to have triggered right after that, but that seems to be an odd thing to be a trigger.

Can anyone verify what causes the music to change?